# Converting certain pixels' RGB color to another color

Tags: java, image, loops, rgb, pixel

> Programming Language: Java

I am trying to convert certain pixels of this image to a different color to reveal a "Secret Message."

[image: Original Image]

> Most of the pixels are:
>
> Red = 0, Green = 64, Blue = 0
>
> The pixels that I want changed to R = 255, G = 255, B = 255 are:
>
> Red = 5, Green = 64, Blue = 5

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Color;

public class ASSN2p2
{
  
  private static int makeRGBColor(int red, int green, int blue)
{
int rgb = 0;
rgb = red*65536 + green*256 + blue;
return rgb;
}
private static int getRed(int pixel)
{
return (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
}
private static int getGreen(int pixel)
{
return (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
}
private static int getBlue(int pixel)
{
return (pixel) & 0xFF;
}
  
  
  
  
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  {
   // int width = 300;
   // int height = 200;    
   BufferedImage image = null;
   File f = null;
    
    try
     {
       f = new File("D:\\2016-2017\\Fall2016\\201_CSCE_Programming\\Assignment 2\\secretmessage.png");
       image = ImageIO.read(f);
       image = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
       System.out.println("Reading Complete");
       BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
       
       //--------------------------------------
       
      
      //-------------------------------------------
      
   
for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
{
 for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
 {
int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
 int r,g,b;
 r = getRed(pixel);
 g = getGreen(pixel);
 b = getBlue(pixel);
if ((r == 5) && (g == 64) && (b == 5))
{
r = 64;
b = 64;
b = 64;
image.setRGB(x,y,makeRGBColor(r,g,b));
} }
}
     }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }

  
        
       // printPixelARGB(pixel);
       // System.out.println("");

    
    
    
    
    

    try
    {
      f = new File("D:\\2016-2017\\Fall2016\\201_CSCE_Programming\\Assignment 2\\output.png");
      ImageIO.write(image, "png", f);
      System.out.println("Writing Complete");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }
    
  }
}
```

This produces this:

[image: Output]

I am having trouble understanding what has gone wrong!

Any assistance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're missing the alpha component of your new color. Change your code to:

```
private static int makeRGBColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
  int rgb = 0xff000000 | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
  return rgb;
}
```

to make sure that the alpha is set to full, otherwise your image will look completely transparent.

Comment: How would I set alpha to full?

Comment: That's what `0xff000000` does.